# Installing Haskell with Homebrew fails

Tags: haskell, homebrew

I had installed Haskell before, but that was hopelessly outdated. I tried to uninstall everything based on the documents I found and reinstalled it using homebrew.

```
brew install ghc cabal-install
```

This succeeded

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ghc-7.10.1_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ghc-7.10.1_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.10.1_1: 5423 files, 821M
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/cabal-install-1.22.2.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring cabal-install-1.22.2.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/cabal-install/1.22.2.0: 6 files, 19M
```

But then I get this:

```
> ghci
-bash: /usr/bin/ghci: No such file or directory
```

And

```
> cabal
-bash: /usr/bin/cabal: No such file or directory
```

Since I can run other packages that are in my Cellar, I would think that I should be able to run these packages as well?

Comment: I can not help you 100% here (it seems to me that your path is just wrong - `/usr/bin/ghci` but you installed into `/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/...` - IMO a symlink would do) but I never tried to install it with homebrew - I used https://ghcformacosx.github.io/ and it worked out of the box without any problem - but I have to admit that I striped OSX for linux again - was not worth the hype for me)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I thought something like that

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some lingering symlinks or similar in `/usr/bin`. Homebrew automatically symlinks binaries from its "cellar" to `/usr/local/bin` (notice that the directory includes `local`).

A reasonable course of action for you might be

1. Check if Homebrew installed `ghc`, `cabal`, etc in `/usr/local/bin` (they should be symlinks pointing to somewhere under `/usr/local/Cellar/`). If they do exist you can conclude that Homebrew did not screw up.
2. Check what kind of thing `/usr/bin/ghci`, `/usr/bin/cabal` actually are: eg `ls -l /usr/bin/ghci`. It will probably tell you that they are symlinks which point to files that don't exist, they are probably left from your previous Haskell installation.
3. Remove the broken symlinks and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is somewhere on your `$PATH`.

(Now there have been people who do not recommend installing GHC using Homebrew, you might want to try the installation instructions found on the Haskell homepage: https://www.haskell.org/downloads. On the other hand I don't see anything too strange in Homebrew's GHC formula, so it might be fine currently.)